# Windows batch logic for skipping powered off computers

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using a third-party utility (setacl.exe) to takes ownership and change permissions of a single file on many networked computers. I tried this using Powershell, but gave up, using setacl.exe with a batch file instead. The script then copies the 32-bit IE executable to the 64-bit folder (the reason this needs to be done is complicated :) )

The batch file works well - it reads the computers I want to make the change on, from a text file - **until I hit a PC that's powered off or has the affected process already running**.

I've been playing with the logic to skip PCs, but I haven't been able to make it work. Can anyone help? The copy section of the script (which works perfectly) as follows:

---

```
@echo off

set Logfile="%~dpn0.log"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (Computers.txt) do robocopy "\\%%i\C$\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer" "\\%%i\C$\Program Files\Internet Explorer" "iexplore.exe" >>%logfile%
```

Comment: this sounds scary what you are attempting to do.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward actually, just the missing IF THEN logic is throwing me for a loop (loop - get it? :) )

Comment: i mean manually managing a microsoft file like that.

Comment: Why do you need to check if the computer is powered off? Just let the ROBOCOPY fail.

Comment: When that happens, the script stops processing and I have to ctrl C to interrupt.

Comment: DWhite - I don't really know what else to do

Comment: aphoria - so I'm guess I'm looking for some logic that skips to the next computer when robocopy fails

Answer (score 0):

how about a ping-check?

```
for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%i') do (
  if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," <your robocopy commandline here>
)
```

just inside your first for-loop.

maybe this should do the trick?

Edit: 
this might be a more understandable version:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "LOGFILE=%~dpn0.log"

FOR /F %%I IN (Computers.txt) DO (
  FOR /F "TOKENS=3,5,7 SKIP=5 DELIMS=,= " %%A IN ('PING -n 1 %%I') DO (
    IF %%~A%%~B%%~C EQU 110 (
      CALL :RoboCopyJob %%I
    )
  )
)

GOTO :EOF


:RoboCopyJob
  ECHO ROBOCOPY "\\%~1\C$\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer" "\\%~1\C$\Program Files\Internet Explorer" "iexplore.exe" /R:0 /NP /LOG+:"%~DP0RoboCopy.log" /TEE >>"%LOGFILE%"
  GOTO :EOF
```

the above code works for me (Save to a *.cmd/*.bat-file) . haven't testet to copy something, used a robocopy-commandline, i would use for such solutions. :)
please have a try.

Comment: I tried this, but the script stalls and I have to interrupt it- the log file just shows a robocopy title and a date stamp

Comment: Now that I've made sure my syntax is correct, it still stalls and the log shows 'Network path not found'

Comment: How would that work with this part of the script (I get 'the syntax of the command is incorrect)?
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (Computers.txt) do (for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%i') do (if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," 
do setacl.exe -on "\\%%i\C$\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -ot file -actn setowner -ownr "n:S-1-5-32-544") >>%logfile%))

Comment: Hmm, how do I add that code in one of those nice little windows?

Answer (score 0):

At a command line, type `ROBOCOPY /?` to see all the options.

This is relevant section in this case:

```
::
:: Retry Options :
::
               /R:n :: number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
               /W:n :: Wait time between retries: default is 30 seconds.

               /REG :: Save /R:n and /W:n in the Registry as default settings.

               /TBD :: wait for sharenames To Be Defined (retry error 67).
```

Add `/R:0` as a parameter to your `ROBOCOPY` command. This will make `ROBOCOPY` retry 0 times before failing.

Comment: Using /R:0 - This fails when it hits a PC that's not on the network - the script stalls and doesn't go to the next PC.

Comment: It should fail when it hits a PC that is unavailable. It may take several seconds for it to fail, but then the `FOR` loop will continue on.